# SSRS: Report label position dynamic

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, reporting-services, label, position

I have a report which displays customer address in multiple labels.

My customers use windowed envelopes for mailing. I need the address labels position to be configurable.

Something like, I'll have a database table which stores the Top/Left position of each label per customer. Based on this table, I need to position the address labels on my report.

I thought, it is doable by expressions, but Location property doesn't provides ability to set an expression and make the label's top and left dynamic.

Anybody, any ideas, on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you cannot set an expression for location property. I want to do this before but it seems that there is no solution for this work.

Comment: After further research, I have started to agree with you, that this cannot be done :-(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the duplicate post

I had the same problem as you did. I got around the problem by using an old HTML trick. It involves using a transparent.gif in an image. You put your image (linked to the gif), then put your label on top. Using a parameter, you can toggle which item to appear by setting an expression in the hidden property for both controls.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, it isn't supported. However, here are two ugly work around possible for basic reporting.

**Work around with padding.**
You can't set formula on the label's location, but you can use padding option instead.

1. So you can set the label as wide as the report and as tall as the region.
2. Also, set the label's horizontal alignment to "Left" and Vertical alignment to "Top".
3. Then, add a formula in left and top paddings to offset the text.

[image]

You can also achieve a right aligned offsetted label by setting the Horizontal alignment to "right" and using right padding instead of the left one to offset the field from the right. With the same recipe, you can offset from the bottom by using "bottom" vertical alignment and bottom padding.

***The ugly side:***
This method will create a mess in the report designer as all dynamic label will overlap each other and take all the space over static label. Also, please note that with this method, you won't be able to do fancy stuff like adding borders around the text and hyperlinks.

**Work around with sub report.**
If the number of different positions for the label(s) are really low. You can create a subreport for each possibility and use a formula to display the right subreport for the right case. Sadly, this doesn't work for labels in the header as subreport aren't allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

No solution, as it is not supported!!!

From MS online community support...

"As far as I know, the position of the textbox in the report is static not dynamic, so it will not shift to left."

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1433297.aspx

Comment: I had the same problem as you did.  I got around the problem by using an old HTML trick.  It involves using a transparent.gif in an image.  You put your image (linked to the gif), then put your label on top.  Using a parameter, you can toggle which item to appear by setting an expression in the hidden property for both controls.