# Vertical alignment of page content

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to vertically align all page content centrally in SQL Reporting Services?

*Further Information:*

I have a grouped tablix that is set to not break across pages. However as a result of this it leaves large blocks of whitespace on the page. I'm looking to vertically align the generated tables centrally on the page as opposed to the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe *this is not possible*, at least there are no "standard" ways / properties to handle this. The closest you could get is setting a certain `Top` value for your content, but if the content is dynamic this won't help much, because you [can't set expressions for location properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726926/419956).

Comment: After much testing and searching online I've come to the same conclusion. Thanks for the response.