# SSRS (2012) How can I keep Image Header visible while scrolling?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Observe! Not Tablix header or Matrix header in fact no header at all, I want a Image that is a report wide image at the top of the reports to be visible when scrolling. 
How can I do that???

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do the same time ago but seems like its not achievable. It is not even possible to use an expression for location property: [SSRS: Report label position dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720346/ssrs-report-label-position-dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the image to part of the main tablix of the page, as another column header above the other columns, then set it to scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

tool box Place Image item in designer header and near row group you can see a small triangle simble .Click it and go to the second option . Now you can see a new group in Column grouping. Select that particular group properties and you can see false in most of the places . Change each false -> true and go to preview and scroll down .

Happy designing ( SML scripting in backend...)

Comment: Can you explain it a ittle more transparent please, Little bit more step by step because I cant refer your answer to the problem hands on.